# LoadDataRow vs. Rows.Add

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `DataTable` in my C#/WPF application which is used to bind results information and show it to the user. The application is asking the core every once in a while for its results, and updates its own table accordingly. The code is:

```
int selfCount = Table.Rows.Count;
int totalCount = result.ResultsTable.Rows.Count;

for (int i = selfCount; i < totalCount; i++)
    Table.LoadDataRow(result.ResultsTable.Rows[i].ItemArray, true);
```

I was wondering whether it's good practice, or is

```
Table.Rows.Add(result.ResultsTable.Rows[i].ItemArray);
```

a better idea:

- I don't care if the same line is added again and again (the results are defined by the user).
- Using `LoadDataRow` causes the app to iterate over the current table for each row of the new table, isn't it?

The only possible problem I can see is in case `Rows.Add` doesn't add the new row at the bottom. Can this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,

```
Table.ImportRow()
```

would be the ideal candidate AFAIK.

Comment: Can you please explain further?

Comment: Because it preserves the properties of the DataRow whereas the other techniques lose this information.

Comment: I'm not sure what properties you mean; I only need to show the information that is in the row's items.